# Exposing Restful webservices ,getting response without json key

Tags: java, rest, web-services, netbeans-8

I am creating restful webservices in the netbeans with the help of database (Mysql) ,
created entity from database and then restful webservice from entity ,Used stored procedure and i am getting response from webservice .

**Returned outpout:**

```
{"attendee":[[13885,4,"Mar 28, 2018 5:36:45 PM",null,null,"Active but not Vefied","5f4db43b5ad965aa1dfd27a2c8feb1e7","9828409828","Sanjay",null,"Sanjay Sharma",null,"Mr"null,"Attendee","sanjay",null,"Mar 28, 2018","Sharma",null,"RegularUser",13882,"password",null]],"success":true}
```

**Required Output :**

```
{"attendee":[["**key**":"13885","**above key is missing**":"4","Mar 28, 2018 5:36:45 PM",null,null,"Active but not Vefied","5f4db43b5ad965aa1dfd27a2c8feb1e7","9828409828","Sanjay",null,"Sanjay Sharma",null,"Mr"null,"Attendee","sanjay",null,"Mar 28, 2018","Sharma",null,"RegularUser",13882,"password",null]],"success":true}
```

in this response key for ***json is empty***.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
    List<Attendee> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    em = this.getEntityManager();
    resultList = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("LOGIN_VALID").setParameter("USER", userName).setParameter("PASS", password).getResultList();
    JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(resultList, new TypeToken<List<Attendee>>() {
    }.getType());
    com.google.gson.JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(resultList).getAsJsonArray();
    System.out.println(" " + jsonArray);
    JsonArray jsonA = je.getAsJsonArray();
    //  System.out.println(" jsonAt=rray "+jsonA);
    if (resultList != null) {
        jo.add("attendee", je);
        jo.addProperty("success", Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        jo.addProperty("success", Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    return Response.ok(jo.toString()).build();
```

Comment: Your required output is not valid JSON. A JSON array can not contain key value pairs like `"key": "13885"`.

Comment: @LutzHorn I am getting the response but json should be int the form of key value pair , here i am getting only values not the keys .